# I am always getting error while using this map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); its not working

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

here is my code inside the fragment

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    map.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

         map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    LatLng wotw = new LatLng(26.912434, 75.787270);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(wotw)
            .title("Walk of the Week"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(wotw));
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));


}
```

I have tried all permissions and I have added in `manifest` also I am getting error this

```
my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

please resolve this Thank you in advance and I would Appreciate every suggestion

Comment: You need to add 'Runtime Permissions' for Android M and later.

Comment: I have done when asking for permission I am getting crash

Answer (score 1):

Before you set `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` you have to declare and check location permissions:

First, you need to declare location permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

After that you need check this permissions granted before you set `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`:

```
String MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE= "LOCATION_PERMISSIONS";


@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
           } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                      new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 
                           MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
                   }
     }
```

Next step you need check this permissions granted:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (permissions.length == 1 &&
          permissions[0] == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION &&
          grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
      // Permission was denied. Display an error message.
    }
}
```

More information you can find in
[Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location)